# CodeIgniter PHP: how to echo a URL segment only if that segment actually exists

Tags: php, codeigniter, conditional-statements, segment

OK, I've been trying to figure this one out for 3 days, but I can't seem to get it right. I'm trying to conditionally echo a URL segment (the page number) only if that segment actually exists for the particular webpage.  Specifically, I'm dealing with the canonical tag in my header template.

**THE BACKGROUND:**

My current code echos paginated directory pages as desired, like this:

```
 https://www.example.com/subjects/apples/2
 https://www.example.com/subjects/apples/3
 https://www.example.com/subjects/apples/4
 etc.
```

It echos directory home pages as NOT desired, like this:

```
 https://www.example.com/subjects/apples/
```

**WHAT MUST STAY THE SAME:**

Paginated directory URLs do NOT end with a forward slash, which is good.

**WHAT MUST CHANGE:**

Directory home pages DO end with a forward slash, which is bad.

**THE EXISTING CODE:**

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $this->config->item("base_url");?><?php echo $category_in_url;?>/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(2);?>" />
```

**THE DESIRED OUTCOME:**

Directory home pages must NOT end with a forward slash.  To stop leaving behind an orphaned forward slash at the end of directory home page URLs, your new code will echo

```
/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(2);?>
```

**only** if segment 2 (i.e., a page number of 2+) actually exists for the particular webpage.  Pages 0 and 1 do not receive a page number in the URL.  So, starting with Page 2, I need to echo that part.  Paginated directory pages should look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/subjects/apples/4
```

Directory home pages should look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/subjects/apples
```

NOTE:  Your solution has to work with my existing code without breaking the PHP.

Thank you in advance for your much-appreciated help!

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $this->config->item("base_url");?><?php echo $category_in_url.((int)$this->uri->segment(2,0) > 1 ? '/'.$this->uri->segment(2) : '');?>" />
```

Comment: Mikeyhun, you officially rule the universe!  Your solution works like a charm in every way!  Thank you so much!